# Support for views in standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

From the web interface to bigquery, it's possible to compose a query and then save it as a view, but this does not seem to work when using standard SQL. For example, when trying to save a view with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` LIMIT 10
```

The error message I get is: "Failed to save view. Invalid table name: `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`"

Are views supported for standard SQL, or will they be in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are views supported for standard SQL, or will they be in the future?

as per [Known Issues and FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/known-issues-and-faq) they [will] become available with standard SQL later this year (2016)